# как мне отловить ошибку?

Tags: php

При добавление проверки на уникальность, получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'ааааа' for key 'lastname'' in
>   C:\openserver\domains\simple-form\add.php:67 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\openserver\domains\simple-form\add.php(67): PDOStatement->execute()
>   #1 {main} thrown in C:\openserver\domains\simple-form\add.php on line 67

Как можно отловить ошибку, и все таки сделать чтобы если имя совпало перезаписать фамилию?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
        humansPdo(lastname,name)
            VALUES
        (:lastName, :name)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        name = :name
        ";

        $query = $dbConn->prepare($sql);

    $query->bindparam(':lastName', $lastName);
    $query->bindparam(':name', $name);
    $query->bindparam(':patronymic', $patronymic);
    $query->bindparam(':patronymic', $patronymic);
    $query->bindparam(':birthday', $birthday);
    $query->bindparam(':snils', $snilsNumber);
    $query->bindparam(':oms', $omsNumber);
    $query->execute();
```

Comment: Ну ок отловили в чём проблема то?

Comment: если в базу записалось то мне нужно ок вывести, если нет то текст ошибку вот в этом и проблема

Comment: Дам наводку. Try catch

Comment: P.s. по-моему вам отвечали уже вчера на этот вопрос

Comment: понятно эксперты собрались. всё работало ок. пока я не добавил проверку на уникальное поле: запрос из такого : > $sql = "INSERT INTO
  humansPdo(lastname,name)
  VALUES
  (:lastName, :name) ";

стал таким:

$sql = "INSERT INTO
  humansPdo(lastname,name)
  VALUES
  (:lastName, :name)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   lastname= :lastname,
   name= :name
   ";

С тех пор не получается отловить ошибку и сделать запись в бд

Answer (score 1):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` срабатывает при совпадении ключа. Ваше поле `lastname` в бд не указано как ключ, поэтому срабатывает ошибка.

Но я вот не пойму, почему у вас поле "Фамилия" должно быть уникальным в базе? Однофамилицы - не, не слышали?

Comment: здесь я подробно описал почему попал в такую ситуацию --> http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556913/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-php-vs-mysql  . Вкратце: В случае совпадения полей a, b, c + d, то обновить поле g
В случае совпадения только поля d, обновить a, b, c + g

Comment: a,b,c - как раз и есть фио

Comment: @stas0k, средствами php делаете выборку и по результату либо `g`, либо `a, b, c + g`