# Как сделать проверку php vs mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, валидация

Как лучше всего организовать такую проверку на дубликат:

> 1. В случае совпадения полей a, b, c + d, то обновить поле g
> 2. В случае совпадения только поля d, обновить a, b, c + g

Сейчас проверка проходит средствами базы вот схема:

```
CREATE TABLE `humans` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `a` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `c` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `d` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `g` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`a`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`b`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`c`)
);
```

Запрос, проверяющий на уникальность:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
    humansPdo(a,b,c,d,g)
VALUES
    (:a, :b, :c, :d, :g)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    g= :g
";
```

Т.е. первое условие работает как нужно, и при совпадении обновляет g. Не пойму как мне сделать вторую проверку, есть какие то примеры идеи?

Comment: У вас что то капитально не так со структурой базы, раз вам потребовались на таблице аж 3 отдельных уникальных ключа. И смысл фразы "совпадения a, b, c+d" абсолютно не ясен. Совпасть может только одно из полей и этого уже достаточно что бы работала часть update. И что такое "совпадение c+d" у вас в БД что ли не может быть одновременно записей с "c=3, d=2" и "c=1, d=4" ?

Comment: a, b, c - это фамилия имя отчество человека , d , g - уникальные номера привязанные к человеку. мне нужно чтобы при записи в базу было две проверки: 

1. если совпало фио + первый уник. номер (d) - то эти поля оставить, а поле g - второй уникальный номер перезаписать в базе, независимо такой же он или нет. молча перезаписать.

2. если фио не совпали, а совпал уникальные номер (d) (выдали новый документ человеку, с новым номером - сменил фамилию) - то его в базе не трогать, а  поля фио и  второй уник. номер перезаписать не проверяя.

Comment: Ваша текущая структура подразумевает что если в БД у вас есть Иванов Сидор Петрович, то вы уже не сможете добавить больше ни одного Иванова, ни одного Сидора и ни одного Петровича. Потому как уникальность полей поддерживается независимо друг от друга. Вам надо для fio делать общий уникальный ключ `unique key(a,b,c)` вместо 3х  отдельных. А по поводу уникальных номеров d и g раз они могут меняться со временем напрашивается их вынесение в отдельную таблицу что бы по любому из старых номеров можно было бы найти того же человека (id человека хранится к номеру). А еще бывают полные тезки ...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556824/как-мне-отловить-ошибку не ваш?

Comment: @Naumov Да наш. Не могу разобраться , вроде бы надо то проверить два раза. А как не пойму. Мне на уровне php это грамотнее сделать или unique key подойдет в моём случае?

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, а где мне тогда проверять ?

Comment: Селектор проверь

Comment: @Naumov ты про что ? какой селектор?

Comment: Что у вас с логикой не так. Вы g называете вторым уникальным номером. Но не решили какие поля перезаписывать в случае его совпадения (все остальные поля не совпадают). И в России огромное количество Ивановых Иванов Ивановечей. Нельзя ФИО делать уникальным

Comment: @Mike попробую нарисовать, какие поля перезаписывать я решил. Всего мне нужно обработать два случая: 1. если пользователь вводит  фамилию имя отчество и первый уникальный номер, которые есть в базе тогда перезаписывается второй уникальный номер, независимо от того такой же он или другой. 2. Второй случай: если пользователь вводит данные и первый уникальный номер совпал , в бд уже есть такая запись, тогда нужно перезаписать фио и второй уникальный номер.  Вот рисунок http://i67.tinypic.com/33wmj5i.png . Мне нужно обработать две ситуации а как это сделать не знаю, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @stas0k Лучше перечитайте то что только что написали (и что написали в вопросе). У вас при варианте 1 надо переписать только второй "уникальный" номер. И в варианте 2 вы так же хотите переписать этот 2й номер. И вы не рассматриваете случая, что если первый уникальный номер уже есть в базе у одной записи, а второй "уникальный" номер при этом так же есть в БД, но у другой записи. В таком случае в первую запись обновить невозможно, потому как сработает проверка уникальности второго номера

Comment: @stas0k Вообще если внимательно вчитаться в то, что вы написали то достаточно проверять уникальность только первого номера и если в БД уже есть запись с таким номером то переписать данные в ней, если нет - то создать новую. По крайней мере у вас в обоих вариантах написано именно это, только разными словами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из комментариев экспертов я сделал вывод что на уровне логики mysql такую проверку мне реализовать невозможно

Или всё же ***Mike*** прав, но он предлагает одну проверку , а мне нужно две:

> ... достаточно проверять уникальность только первого номера и если в БД уже есть запись с таким номером то переписать данные в ней, если нет - то создать новую.

Исходные данные:

бд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно проверять всего два варианта:

> 1. Если *ФИО* и *номер паспорта* уже есть у какой то записи в таблице, тогда обновить эту запись только в части поля номер *водительского удостоверения*
> 2. Если уже имеется одна запись с таким же *номером паспорта*, тогда обновить в этой записи нужно поля *фио* и *номер водительского удостоверения.*

Comment: но как это проверить с помощью php ума не приложу. покажите?

Comment: @Mike я призываю вас, покажите как можно выполнить это одним запросом?

Comment: Но ваш первый пункт ничем не отличается от второго. Если паспорт и ФИО совпали и мы в этой записи перепишем водительское удостоверение И перепишем ФИО - это нам ничего не испортит, потому как ФИО меняется само на себя. Во втором случае мы делаем то же самое - только ФИО переписывается на не точно такое же. Итого приходим просто к поддержанию уникальности номера паспорта с переписыванием всех остальных полей, простым insert ... on duplicate key update